# how to split spark dataframe to list of dataframe by cols or conditions

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have billions of rows data frame, I want to split this data frame into hundreds by value of some label cols.

my data like this

```
value|col1|col2|col3
1    | "a"|"b" |"c"
2    | "a"|"b" |"b"
3    | "a"|"x" |"c"
4    | "d"|"x" |"b"
```

my expected is like this

```
result:Map[Row,Dataframe]

result(Row(a,b))

value|col1|col2|col3
1    | "a"|"b" |"c"
2    | "a"|"b" |"b"
------
result(Row(a,x))

3    | "a"|"x" |"c"
------
result(Row("d","x))

4    | "d"|"x" |"b"
```

my solution is to use recurse left semi or filter, but I consider using some greater solution as `random split` does.
my solution is this first answer to this question, please give me some advice or suggestion

```
result:Map[Row,Dataframe] = split_data(data,Seq("col1","col2"))
```

**I have two questions**

> 1. I want to get a nested split map like this:

```
def nestedSplit(data:DataFrame,cols:Seq[Seq[String]]):Map[Row,Map[Row,Map[Row,Dataframe]]]

result:Map[Row,Map[Row,Dataframe]] = split_data(data,Seq(Seq("col1","col2"),Seq("col3"))

#Map nested rows nums based on cols. length

#scala is a static type of language, this demand may be is hard to get
```

> 2. a better solution about data frame split

thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, not}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Column, DataFrame, RelationalGroupedDataset, Row, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{BooleanType, StructField, StructType}

import scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap

trait Split {

  import Split._

  val data: DataFrame

  val keySchema: StructType


  def info(): DataFrame

  def agg: RelationalGroupedDataset

  val keys: List[Row]

  lazy val result: DataSplitMap = transform

  def transform: Split.DataSplitMap
}

object Split {

  type DataSplitMap = LinkedHashMap[Row, DataFrame]

  type DataSplitMapper = (DataSplitMap, StructType)

  def empty(structType: StructType): DataSplitMapper = (LinkedHashMap[Row, DataFrame](), structType)

  def empty(): DataSplitMap = LinkedHashMap[Row, DataFrame]()

  def rowsToDataFrame(data: Traversable[Row], schema: StructType): DataFrame = {
    val spark = SparkSession.active
    spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data.toSeq: Seq[Row]), schema)
  }

  def combine(data: Traversable[DataFrame]): DataFrame = data.toArray.reduce(_ union _)

  def combine(data: DataSplitMap, schema: StructType): (DataFrame, DataFrame) = (rowsToDataFrame(data.map(_._1), schema), combine(data.map(_._2)))


  def filter(data: DataFrame, conditionData: DataFrame, filterNames: Seq[String]): DataFrame = {
    data.join(conditionData, filterNames, "left_semi")
  }

  def split(data: DataFrame, condition: Any): Split = {
    condition match {
      case c: Column => new FilterSplit(data, c)
      case n: Seq[String] => new SemiSplit(data, n)
      case _ => null
    }

  }

}

class SemiSplit(dataSrc: DataFrame, colNames: Seq[String]) extends Split {

  import Split._

  val data = dataSrc.repartition(colNames.map(col): _*)

  val keySchema: StructType = data.select(colNames.head, colNames.tail: _*).schema

  lazy val info: DataFrame = agg.count()

  lazy val keys: List[Row] = info.drop("count").collect().toList

  def transform: DataSplitMap = {
    val result: DataSplitMap = Split.empty()
    keys.foreach(x => {
      val filter_df = Split.rowsToDataFrame(Seq(x), keySchema)
      result += (x -> Split.filter(data, filter_df, colNames))
    })
    result
  }

  override def agg: RelationalGroupedDataset = data.groupBy(colNames.head, colNames.tail: _*)
}

class FilterSplit(dataSrc: DataFrame, condition: Column) extends Split {

  override val data = dataSrc

  override val keySchema: StructType = StructType.apply(Seq(StructField("condition", BooleanType, false)))

  override lazy val info: DataFrame = agg.count()

  override val keys: List[Row] = List(Row(true), Row(false))


  override def transform = {
    val result = Split.empty()
    result += Row(true) -> data.filter(condition)
    result += Row(false) -> data.filter(not(condition))
    result
  }

  override def agg: RelationalGroupedDataset = dataSrc.withColumn("condition", condition).groupBy(col("condition"))
}
```

my Split is well work;

```
Split.split(data,Seq("col1","col2)).result
```

My spark version is `2.4.5` and the scala version is `2.11`.